# Using Google places API without Google Maps but showing the selected result on OSM map

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-places-api, google-search-api

We want to use Google Maps API and Places Autocomplete API in our android applications. Before using that we want to be clear on your ‘terms of use’ of using those APIs. We checked Google documentation. But still we are having some queries which are as follows:

1. We want to use 2 fullscreen views. In first view, there will be OpenStreet map over that one search button will be. If the user clicks that search button, second view will be opened in which there will be one search bar and space to show search results.  Here we want to use Places Autocomplete API for searching places. So that we will add ‘Powered By Google’ logo in this page.

   Once the result has been selected, the user will be redirected to first view(map page) and that location will be shown as marker there. Could you please confirm that is this acceptable and is this correct way of using Places API without Google Map? If not, could you please let me know the correct way of doing this.
2. If we use Google Maps in our android application, is it acceptable if we are showing moving cars or trucks over the map? Is there any paid services available to avail this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Referring to the first question, you should follow the paragraph 10.4 (d) of Google Maps API Terms of Service that reads:

> **No use of Content without a Google map.** Unless the Maps APIs Documentation expressly permits you to do so, you will not use the Content in a Maps API Implementation without a corresponding Google map. For example, you may display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map because the Maps APIs Documentation expressly permits this use.

As far as I know the Premium plan has a special type of license that allows to use Google Maps API data without a map, but you should purchase this license in order to be compliant.

Referring to the second question, you are going to implement an asset tracking application that also requires a Premium plan asset tracking license according to the paragraph 10.4 (c,iv) of ToS:

> **No asset-tracking unless you have purchased the applicable enterprise license.** Unless you have purchased an applicable Premium Plan or Maps APIs for Work license that expressly permits you to do so, you will not use the Service or Content for commercial asset-tracking or in Maps API Implementations whose primary purpose is to assess vehicle insurance risks.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms-20180207#10-license-restrictions

It looks like in both cases you need a Premium plan license, so I would suggest reaching out to the Google Sales team to discuss this question with them:

https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/

I hope my answer clarifies your doubts!